# .NET 8 Azure Functions: setting System.Text.JsonSerializer defaults

Tags: c#, azure-functions, system.text.json, azure-functions-isolated

I'm trying to set a convertor to be used on every request to an Azure Function using a `JsonResult`.

I'm using the new VS2022 templates for azure functions using .NET 8. This means: the extension `ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication` is used and not the older `ConfigureFunctionWorker`.

I'm trying to set the options as it seems to be used in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/SystemTextJsonResultExecutor.cs#L26

but it isn't working.

```
.ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication((hostBuilderContext, functionsWorkerApplicationBuilder) =>
    {
        functionsWorkerApplicationBuilder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
            options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
            options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
            #if DEBUG
            options.SerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
            #endif
        });
    }
```

does absolutely nothing.

I can get it working if I replace it with a call like:

```
functionsWorkerApplicationBuilder.Services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

But that might drag in a lot of stuff I don't want or need.

Does anyone know the proper way to set the jsonserialization defaults?

And please don't answer with answers that are valid for older .NET version or Newtonsoft. Especially newtonsoft seems to be on the way out of the framework.

edit:

I appreciate people looking over my question, but I explicitly asked for an answer pertaining to the latest way of building Azure Functions as advertised by Microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#http-trigger
So not the build in classes HttpRequestData and HttpResponseData, but the classes OkObjectResult en JsonResult that come from the new mvc core integration. These seem to be the current way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. There is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions and there is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions.

JsonResult which works with IActionResultExecutor uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions.

So this will work:

```
        services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
        });
```

But this won't:

```
        services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
            options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
            options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
       });
```

This cost me hours. Wish microsoft didn't reuse classnames so blatently

Comment: I've converted a .net8 isolated project to the new `IAsyncResult` and `HttpRequest` attributes. But weirdly, I found the opposite from the above. For the JSON options to apply, I have to use `.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>` rather than using the MVC namespace. Othrewise the options are ignored. Does it depend on the exact package versions used? I can post mine in an answer if anyone is interested.

Comment: @AndrewB Yes it very much depends on the exact classes used. That is the whole point of the answer :) Which JsonOptions you need to use depends very much in what you actually use to generate your reply. As you are not using the MVC classes as in the new .net 8 templates. My answer might not apply to your situation. But one or the other should work.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker => { })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services
            .AddHttpClient() // etc
            .Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Whatever options
                options.AllowTrailingCommas = true;
                options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                options.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                options.IncludeFields = true;
            })
```

And then the default Json methods automatically use that config, e.g. when using `HttpRequestData` and `HttpResponseData`

```cs
[Function(nameof(SomePostMethod))]
public Task<HttpResponseData> SomePostMethod([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "my-api/route")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    var received = await req.ReadFromJsonAsync<MyType>(); // Automatically uses your Json options.

    var result = DoSomethingWithReceivedData(received);

    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(result); // Automatically uses your Json options.
    return response;
};
```

This is from a .NET 8 Isolated Functions application that I'm developing. Definitely works for me.

Comment: You are using the old HttpResponseData en HttpRequestData classes. If you update your templates in VS2022 you'll discover microsoft switched to using mvc core integration using the classes IActionResult, OkObjectResult and JsonResult and such. I added a link to my question that explains that what you are doing is now only kept for backwards compatibility. See the wording under the header HttpTrigger.
I need my answer for the new way of doing things.

Comment: No probs. Regardless of the response method, can you try including the .Configure<JsonSerializerOptions> in your DI service config anyway?

Comment: already tried that, but I finally figured it out. There are two JsonOptions classes, one under Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions and one Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions. I configured the wrong one.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in .NET 8 and Azure Functions v4. Setting services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
}
in Program.cs doesn't apply properly to my input JSON in my Azure Function

Comment: I wonder if the difference is that I'm using the vanilla Azure Function `HttpResponseData` etc, as @zu1b spotted. It'd be interesting to know if that's related.

Comment: @OliverNilsen The new stuff in .net 8 uses mvc actionresult. Httpresponsedata (now referred to as built-in is obsolete. Get a up to dat version of VS, make sure you have updated your function template (under settings) and start a fresh project, you will see the new stuff

Comment: @zu1b I have updated VS 2022 to latest version. Shouldn't it update the Azure Function template by default or do I need to do something manually?

Comment: @OliverNilsen Yes, there is a manual step. in Vs2022 under menu tools then options you can search for "Azure". Under "projects and solutions" there is an subitem "azure functions" It has two check for update buttons. Don't know why this got so hidden.

Comment: @zu1b Thank you for this brilliant tip. I just tried and went  to Tools -> Options -> then under Projects and Solutions find Azure Functions and click on "Check for update button". I have always assumed that by having the latest VS version I would have the latest project templates.

Comment: @OliverNilsen I expected the same, we all learn :)